# Extract text out of two lines in a file and output them in a table

Tags: php, extract

I am trying to make a PHP script for my school. School's web directory has about 100 text files, one text file for each student. Every text file has a two lines like:

```
stu $id = '12701';
stu $name = 'alex';
```

I want to echo out this id and name value in a table. But those two line are random. It might be at line number 23 and 24, or sometimes 45 and 46.

Here's my attempt:

```
$directory     = 'lessons/'; // The directory to the lesson text files
$linesToReturn = 50; //  i tired to read top 50 lines , so i can grab from them.

// Find all files in the directory which are .txt files
foreach (glob($directory . "*.txt") as $filename)
{
    // Open the file
    if ($handle = @fopen($filename, "r"))
    {
        $x = 0; // Start the line counter

        // Cycle each line until end or reach the lines to return limit
        while (!feof($handle) or $x < $linesToReturn)
        {
            $line                 = fgets($handle); // Read the line
            $lessons[$filename][] = $line;
            $x++; // Increase the counter
        }
    }
}

// creates a blank list if no files or valid files were found.
if (!isset($lessons))
    $lessons = array();

// The rest of the page just builds a simple table to display each lesson.-
echo '<h1>id & names</h1>';
echo '<table>';
echo '<th>id</th><th>name</th>';

foreach ($lessons as $file => $details)
{
    echo '<tr><td>' . $details[0] . '</td><td>' . $details[1] . '</td> </tr> ';
}
echo '</table>';
```

But this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: sure .. 

`pastebin.com/raw.php?i=GmSdY4NP`

facing prblem to post whole code here :( 
@AmalMurali

Comment: I saw your previous (now deleted) comment but I'm unable to access pastebin.com. Weird. Can you try another site, like http://pastie.org ?

Comment: http://pastie.org/8983134

@AmalMurali